# Is carrying with a shinui in a rabbinically prohibited area permitted for a mitzvah

Tags: halacha, shabbat, derabanan, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, orach-chaim

According to Halacha, is it permissible to carry with a *shinui* in a place where it is only rabbinically prohibited to carry in the first  place if done for a mitzvah?

So for example, if a Jew carried a bottle of wine for kiddush with a *shinui* in a place that is not a biblical reshut harabim, to deliver it for themself and others to make kiddush, is that permissible?

The reason I ask is because there is a general principle in Halacha that rabbis don’t make injunctions for other rabbinic injunctions, so would this be a Derabbanan on a Derabbanan that could be permitted for the need of a mitzvah?

Comment: I found conflicting rulings [here](https://ph.yhb.org.il/01-09-11/) and [here](https://din.org.il/2019/02/26/%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%9D-%D7%93%D7%95%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA/). And I'm not sure if your example would qualify as a true shinui or mitzvah.

Comment: Do you want to know specifically about shinui? Because the Mishna Berura talks about 'less than four Amos at a time' carrying in a Reshus Harabbim derabanan for a mtizva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Orach Chayim 349:5 it says:

> אסור להוליך חפץ פחות פחות מארבע אמות ואפי' בין השמשות ואפי' בכרמלית
>
> It's forbidden to carry something less than four Amos at a time, even at twilight and even in a karmelis

The mishna Berura comments there (seif katan 19):

> ואפי' בכרמלית - הטעם דאם נקיל בזה קרוב הדבר שיוליך ד"א בב"א [ט"ז] ובביאור הגר"א כתב הטעם דכל דבר שאסרו בר"ה משום שבות ה"ה שאסור בכרמלית ואם הוא בה"ש גם כן דהוי תרתי לטיבותא דעת הט"ז וא"ר להקל בזה אך לפי המבואר לעיל בסימן שמ"ב דלא התירו שבות בין השמשות כ"א לצורך מצווה או במקום הדחק אפשר דהכא נמי אין להקל אלא בכגון זה
>
> Even in a karmelis - the reason is that it we are lenient by this, then it's very likely that he'll carry for Amos at once [Ta"Z]. And in Bi'ur HaGR"A he wrote that the reason is that anything forbidden mid'rabannan in a Reshus Harabbim, is also forbidden in a Karmelis. However, if it is *also* twilight, which will be two redeeming factors, the Ta"Z and the Eliya Rabbah hold that we can be lenient. However, based on what was explained earlier in siman 342, that melacha mid'rabannan was only allowed at twilight for a mitzva or in a time of great need, it's possible that here as well we'd only be lenient in a case like that.

However, in the Bi'ur halacha (ואפילו בכרמלית) he brings Achronim who argue on the Shulchan aruch and say that less than four Amos at a time in a karmelis should be completely muttar. He himself suggests that even when it's shabbos (and not twilight), carrying less than 4 amos at a time in a Karmelis **for a mitzva** would be allowed, and says it might be a machlokes Rashi/ Tosafos, or maybe Tosafos even agrees that it's allowed, because this would be a case of שבות דשבות לצורך מצווה - a derabanan of a derabanan for the sake of a mitzva (as suggested in the OP). In the end, he leaves it in a *tzarich iyun*.